# Type parameter 'TProperty' for TextBoxFor cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following that is failing at design time in my ASP.NET MVC project (VB language):

```
@ModelType Project.Models.InformationEntity

@* FormRowBegin is my custom extension *@
@Using Html.FormRowBegin("Name")
         @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(i) i.Name) @* ERROR HERE *@
     End Using
```

At compile-time, it's giving me an error saying it can't infer the property type of Name, which name is defined in the model as:

```
Public Class InformationEntity

    Public Property Name As String
```

This is causing intellisense to break, which is greatly slowing me down.  Any idea why this is problematic in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I would guess your view isn't properly referencing your model. Maybe the namespace is incorrect, or there is another compilation error you're missing. try commenting out the offending code int he view and recompile, see if something else fails.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@Using Html.FormRowBegin("Name")
         @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(i) i.Name) @* ERROR HERE *@
     End Using
```

to

```
@Using Html.FormRowBegin("Name")
    Html.TextBoxFor(Function(i) i.Name) 
End Using
```

Note @ missing from second line

The @ symbol in razor changes the language being parsed from vb/c# to Html